# Estoy creando de forma dinámica el name de mi input

Tags: python, django, template

Estimados estoy en el template construllendo un grupo de input a través de un for, pero no puedo dejar dinamico el name del input

```
<p>Esta apunto de Ingresar <strong>{{arr_num_platos|length}}</strong> platos</p> 

{% for plato in arr_num_platos %}

    <p>----------------- Plato -------------------</p>        
    <p>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nom_plato">
    <p>Precio: <input type="number" name="precio_plato">
    <p>Tipo: <input type="text" name="tipo_plato">
        
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

El name quedaria de esta forma `name="nom_plato{{plato}}"` así tendría un numero único para diferenciarla del resto